# How can I select random samples from several matrices in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, sampling

Using MATLAB, I have several 8760x1 matrices. I need to randomly select some data from the first one, and then select the data from the other matrices, but the data that is on the same position as got from the first i.e.

```
data1 = [a b c d e];
data2 = [f g h i j];
```

I datasample [a c d], then I need to select [f h i], on this order, giving me:

```
out1 = [a c d]
out2 = [f h i]
```

is `datasample` the best tool for this? Or how can I do it?
Thanks.

Comment: Use datasample for data1 with second output also captured. Use the second output from datasample to index into data2 and others.

Comment: Are you selecting **with** or **without** replacement?

Comment: I was using without but without success but the solution provided by @TonyTannous worked. However, I need to do something a little more complex, if possible. I properly extracted lets say 6000 of the 8760 numbers but I need to randomly extract more 1500 **only** of the remaining 2760 and then, the remaining 1260 on a third vector.

Comment: @rayryeng he wants unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datasample will serve well, as long as you use the non-replacing form (I guess you don't want repeated output. If you're ok with that, then ignore the 'Replace' flag). The index output will also be unsorted, so you can perfectly use it for data2:

```
data1 = [a b c d e];
data2 = [f g h i j]
[out1,idx] = datasample(data1,k,'Replace',false);
out2=data2(idx);
```

I see that you also "need to randomly extract more 1500 only of the remaining 2760 and then, the remaining 1260 on a third vector.", you can use the idx info to ignore that set:

```
idx_notused=setdiff(1:size(data1,1),idx); %finds all positions not selected previously
[out1_v2,idx2] = datasample(data1(idx_notused),k,'Replace',false); %k=1500
idx2=idx_notused(idx2); %so it maps with the original data
out2_v2=data2(idx2);

%and again for the remaining 1260:
idx_remaining=setdiff(1:size(data1,1),[idx idx2]);
out1_v3=data1(idx_remaining);
out2_v3=data2(idx_remaining);
```

Comment: thanks! It's working flawlessly. @ana If you don't mind, let me ask you something else: If the input `data1` is a `8760x2` instead of `8760x1`, as I am trying, the first datasampling works fine, and returns a `6000x2` matrix, however, the remaining return a `1500x1` and 1260x1`

Comment: Ok, made it by adding `:` to `(idx_notused,:)`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
mat1 = [4, 3, 5, 4];
mat2 = [1, 1, 2, 2];

s = size(mat1);
[v] = randperm(s(2), 2); <--- remember the indices 


ret = mat1(v);
ret = [ret; mat2(v)];
enter code here


out1 = ret(1, 1:end);
out2 = ret(2, 1:end);
```

**EDIT**

```
[v] is a 1/0 vector which represents the places chosen to pick from values. 
now to choose from the data left, we need to extract the data not picked and  
pick from it.

v2 = (1-v);
TempMat = Mat(v2);

TempMat is the remaining data not picked in first place.
```

Comment: Care to explain what does those 2's stand for on randperm?

Comment: @Paulos, yes sorry...
`s(2)`  is the size of the vector and 2 is the number of values which I wanted to pick. You could put whatever number you want `randperm(s(2), n)` instead of n. As long is its smaller or equal to the total number of values in the vector.

Comment: I was getting a `k>n`error there but I noticed my input data was indeed `8760x1` and not a `1x8760` so, I placed a `randperm(s(1), n)`. Then I had to transpose both `mat1(v)` and `mat2(v)` on `ret` to fix it. Don't know if there is any easier way to "fix" it.

Comment: any idea how should I redo the sampling again on the same input data, now with fewer values but **only** on the remaining/not sampled units? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the solution below will fit your needs. In vector k2 you will have n distinct indices for using in the matrices that you want.

```
k1=randperm(length(data1)); 
k2=k1(1:n)    % row of n samples
out1=data1(k2);
out2=data2(k2);
```

Answer (score 0):

For sampling without repetitions, you can use [`randperm`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html), the fact that you resample from the same data in 'chunks' of 1500 elements or so, does not change the basic fact the you sample without repetition. So, all you need is to reorder all data, and then reshape it into the size you want:

```
data1 = ('abcdewryt').';
data2 = ('fghijvbnm').';
k = 2; % samlpe size
N = 3; % no. of times to resample
rand_ind = randperm(size(data1,1)); % reorder all your data
out1 = reshape(data1(rand_ind(1:k*n)),[k,n]); % extract output from data1 in a shuffled order
out2 = reshape(data2(rand_ind(1:k*n)),[k,n]); % extract output from data2 in a shuffled order
left1 = data1(rand_ind(k*n+1:end)); % all what's left in data1
left2 = data1(rand_ind(k*n+1:end)); % all what's left in data2
```

now you have in each column of `out`s on sample from the data, and you have `N` columns for resampling the data `N` times. All what's left in the original vectors is in the `left`s.

An example of a result:

```
out1 =
ywb
det
out2 =
nvg
ijm
left1 =
a
r
c
left2 =
a
r
c
```

Comment: Whats wrong with my answers who's similar to yours ? + he wanted to take another sample from remained data.

Comment: @TonyTannous you right, I noticed his other question after I posted that, and didn't have time to fix it.